# Symbol hiding: visibility attribute gives different result compared to a version script for an ELF shared object

Tags: c++, linker, elf

I am a bit confused by the symbol hiding techniques. As well as I am aware, there are two ways to hide a symbol of a shared library (besides stripping the whole section header table out):

- `-fvisibility=hidden` flag or the in-code compiler attribute.
- version script for the linker.

I have a shared library `A` which is linked statically with another (`B`) which uses a bundled `libfmt` in a header-only version. In my library `A` I want to hide exactly all symbols but one. What I see when using `-fvisibility=hidden` is that my symbol which I wanted is exported, but also a weak symbol of the `libfmt` library:

`nm -D --defined-only`

```
002f8ec8 V fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::signs
```

`objdump -t liba.so | c++filt | grep fmt::v6::internal::basic_data\<void\>`

```
00000000004cdbe8 l  O .data 0000000000000004  fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::signs
```

But when using a version script:

```
{   
    global:   
        extern "C++" {
            mynamespace::*;   
        };

    local:
        *;
};
```

I see nothing in the `nm -D --defined-only` output except for the symbols from my desired namespace `mynamespace`, while `objdump -t` shows:

```
00000000004d4e28 u  O .data 0000000000000004 fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::signs
```

Besides the difference in the address offset, I see that the symbol group has changed - from `local` to `unique global`, what according to the manual of `objdump` means:

> "l"
> "g"
> "u"
> "!" The symbol is a local (l), global (g), unique global (u), neither global nor local (a space) or both global and local (!).  A symbol can be neither local or global for a variety of reasons, e.g., because it is used for debugging, but it is probably an indication of a bug if it is ever both local and global.  Unique global symbols are a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

The questions:

1. Where did the symbol go? Why can't I see it with `nm -D` anymore? The `.dynsym` section still should be there as well as its headers, as well as these symbols in it, is this correct? My understanding is that as this symbol is defined as

   ```cpp
   template <typename T> const char basic_data<T>::signs[] = {0, '-', '+', ' '};
   ```

   , shouldn't it be there due to a vague linkage?
2. Did the linkage become strong? Previously it was `V` and so it could have been "overridden" by, for example, an `LD_PRELOAD` string, but now, as to repeat the `man objdump`:

   > For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

   Will it cause a collision if another symbol with the same name is found by the runtime linker?

I am not sure whether I need an MCVE for this.

Comment: Please don't use `objdump` when dealing with ELF -- it will produce misleading results (for complicated reasons). Use `readelf` instead.

Comment: I am now really curious about `objdump` and why would it give different results... I checked with `nm` and it seemed to be the same. Is there any blog post describing the issues one might have with it?

Comment: "I am now really curious ..." -- just ask a question?